# angularjs ionic - ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hy guys,

may you could help me understanding this issue.

index.html

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

    <div class="upage vertical-col left" id="mainpage" ng-controller="myController"><ion-list class="widget uib_w_4 d-margins" data-uib="ionic/list" data-ver="0">
            <ion-item class="item widget uib_w_5" data-uib="ionic/list_item" data-ver="0" ng-repeat="daten in datenListe" ng-controller="myController"> Stunde: {{daten.anzahl}} item</ion-item>
        </ion-list>

        <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="daten in datenListe">
            {{daten.anzahl}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('myController',['$scope', function($scope){

&scope.datenListe = [
    {'anzahl' : 'noch keine', 'datum': '2207'}
    ];

$scope.addHours= function(){}}]);
```

ng-repeat should now display all "anzahl" from the array datenListe in a list. 
why isn't it working. the controller and the module is known in this div. could you explane me that?

thank you

Comment: ok, my bad. but this seems not to be the only problem.

Comment: I added the script in the <head> block. there are also the others, like angular and ionic. But it just works if I do that in the <Body> tag. why that? If I do so, it works. All other scripts are implemented in the <head> block and they are working.

Comment: your script is likely crashing when you try to load `myController` inside an element block that is already using `myController`.  you only need to declare `ng-controller` once.

Answer (score 0):

It was just some typo mentionned in comment. You can find the working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b3b16d5x/).

Now, as regards the code.

**Html :**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

    <div class="upage vertical-col left" id="mainpage" ng-controller="myController"><ion-list class="widget uib_w_4 d-margins" data-uib="ionic/list" data-ver="0">
            <ion-item class="item widget uib_w_5" data-uib="ionic/list_item" data-ver="0" ng-repeat="daten in datenListe" ng-controller="myController"> Stunde: {{daten.anzahl}} item</ion-item>
        </ion-list>

        <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="daten in datenListe">
            {{daten.anzahl}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

As Claies mentionned, you can't have the same `ng-controller` in each div.

**Controller :**

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('myController',['$scope', function($scope){

$scope.datenListe = [
    {'anzahl' : 'noch keine', 'datum': '2207'}
    ];

$scope.addHours= function(){}}]);
```

Here there is only typo mistake on your delcaration of the list.